# Is there a method to recover camphene from sublimation at ambient conditions?

Tags: sublimation

Camphene solidifies and sublimates at ambient room temperature below 45°C. I'm aware that a glass funnel is often used to separate mixtures through sublimation of the volatile component (in this case camphene) from another material.

Is it possible to recover sublimated camphene using this or another method?

Comment: I think that easy setup should work. Are you afraid that it does not condensate ?

Comment: Yes. I'm worried the vapor will not condense on the inside of the glass funnel, and instead become a semi-solid or liquid mess. I think it's completely solid and sublimates at 20°C, and at around 25°C it starts to become semi-solid. At 45°C it's almost completely melted.

Comment: Cab you adapt something to be a cold finger? In principle you can use a beker full of water if you can confine the vapours.  Roll something around it

Comment: Thanks Alchemista! I think you had the right idea for sure.

Comment: Yes the answer confirms this

Answer (score 1):

MIT has a brilliant technique for sublimating and condensing:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBNELFi5XiY

The sample is placed in a culture dish sitting on a hotplate. The lid is placed on top.  Finally a beaker with ice is placed on top of the dish to condense the sublimate. After a while crystals form on the top of the lid. These pure crystals are periodically scraped with a policeman and collected.